# How to take Absolute and relative Xpath's from Firefox 58.0 Version

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox-addon, firebug, firefox-57+

I am unable to add Firebug and Fire path Add-on's to Firefox 58.0 version. And Because of that reason, Xpath's are not available. Able to take relative Xpath. But I want to take both Xpath's.

Comment: firebug and fire path is not supported in newer version of firefox.

Answer (score 0):

The [Inspector of the Firefox DevTools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector) allows you to copy the absolute XPath of an element via the context menu.

[image: Copy XPath of an element in Firefox DevTools]

They currently don't allow to copy the relative XPath, though, but there is already an [enhancement request filed to add that option](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1410810).

Having said that, there is also an option to copy the CSS selector path for an element. And as Selenium also supports CSS selectors to choose elements, this is a viable alternative to XPaths in many cases.